# Create Sum of calculated columns in Microsoft Reporting Services like Fibonacci series

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Help me, please.

I have a Tablix with `column` group that shows values for each month.

Like the exemple:

```
 JUN/2012|JUL/2012                                                         
 15,00   |26,00                                                               
 15,00   |41,00
```

I want to sum up the values in the second line, row 2 of second month needs to be value of first month + second month.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function in the Report Code to keep a running total value, like below:

```
Dim runningTotals As System.Collections.Hashtable


Public Function AddRunningTotalValue(ByVal dateStr As Object, ByVal amount As Object)
        If (runningTotals Is Nothing) Then
            runningTotals = New System.Collections.Hashtable
        End If
        If (Not runningTotals.Contains(dateStr)) Then
            runningTotals.Add(dateStr, amount)
       End If
       AddRunningTotalValue = amount
End Function

Public Function GetRunningTotalValue(ByVal dateStr)
    If (Not runningTotals.Contains(dateStr)) Then
        GetRunningTotalValue = 0
    End If        
        If (runningTotals.Contains(dateStr)) Then
            For Each dateStrPair As System.Collections.DictionaryEntry In runningTotals
                If dateStrPair.Key.ToString() = dateStr Then
                GetRunningTotalValue = dateStrPair.Value
            End If
        Next
        End If
End Function
```

Of course you would modify the get function to only return the sum of the month values that you want to add together.